# Property or get method with cached result

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns

I have a method that takes around 200ms to run and would therefor like to cache the result. This result will be used frequently, but it never changes.

I'm not entirely sure what the best solution would be for this, should I put this to a property or a get method?

As an example:

1

```
private string _result;
public string Result => _result ?? (_result = GetSlowResult());
```

2

```
private string _result;
public string GetResult() => _result ?? (_result = GetSlowResult());
```

Personally, from a property I typically expect it to be available "now" rather than "later" but with a Get method I expect the result to always retrieve a fresh  `GetSlowResult` rather than using a cached value. I could change the method name to `GetCachedResult` but I'm not sold on that either as then it would seem you need to have called a `GetResult` method first.

Are there any guidelines to this? What do you prefer?

Comment: This might be interesting: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225354/logic-inside-class-properties-setters-getters

Comment: Thanks @Denxorz, that was a useful topic indeed containing some decent insights. I've settled now on the property.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use the `Lazy<T>` class. It causes you to pass a factory that talks about how to create that object, and after that, it is created only the first time you ask for it, and then uses the same reference(cached value).

Here's how it would look:

```
Lazy<T> Result = new Lazy<T>(GetSlowResult); //T is your type
```

Then, to use the result, just get her property `Value`:

```
T myResult = Result.Value;
```

You can see more about this in the [official dotnet docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Thanks, I know about the Lazy class but I don't have to have to add .Value on every call. Which means I would then still need to use another property or a method again, which means my original question remains.

Comment: @TheCookiesDog Choosing between using a method or a property in this case seems only a matter of taste. I would use a property: `T Result => LazyResult.Value;`

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with read-only property and a method that fills the property.

If you know that result will be needed, you can load it at the begining - during startup of a service, activation ov view etc.

I mostly use [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/) in WPF apps, so it would look like that:

```
// ViewModel constructor
GetResult = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () => _model.GetResultAsync()); // notice that method is async
// there is also overload with CancelationToken

_result = GetResult.Retry(3).ToProperty(this, x => x.Result); // we can retry few times and we get change notification

GetResult.Subscribe(result =>{
 // do something as soon as the result is loaded
});   

GetResult.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe( errorHandler);

// ViewModel properties
private ObservableAsProperetyHelper<ResultType> _result;

public ResultType Result => _result.Value;

// view constructor

this.WhenActivated(d =>{ // d is CompositeDisposable for cleanup
  ViewModel.GetResult.Execute().Subscribe().DisposeWith(d); // cancel command if the view is deactivated before it's finished
});
```

That way you can make async call in proper moment and store the result for later. You can also easily refresh the result - that becomes dirty when using lazy properties alone.

On another plus side, you can easily create loading spinner:

```
_isBusy = GetResult.IsExecuting.ToProperty(this, x => x.IsBusy);
```

I followed this pattern in a always-on windows service running custom HTTP server in the background. You can `await GetResult.Execute()` if you want to enforce loading at a particular moment.

In my practice, this pattern shows very little shortcomings - main one is boilerplate code, but with proper tools it can be written really fast.

If you are creating some service type app, console or whatever, MVVM pattern is still very usefull, you just don't do views.